# Froala custom template (button)

Tags: javascript, html, froala

Can i add button that will add template. For ex:

When i click this btn i do:

```
$(function() {
  $.FroalaEditor.DefineIcon("quote", {NAME: "quote-left"});
  $.FroalaEditor.RegisterCommand("customQuote", {
    title: "qoute",
    focus: true,
    undo: true,
    icon: "quote",
    callback: function() {
        var text = this.selection.text();
        var wrapper = "&nbsp<div class='quote-wrap'>";

        wrapper += "<span class='quote-wrap__content'>" + (text || "text") + "</span>";
        wrapper += "<p class='quote-wrap__info'>";
        wrapper += "<span class='quote-wrap__info_author'>author</span>";
        wrapper += "<span class='quote-wrap__info_post'>post</span>";
        wrapper += "</p></div><p></p>";

        this.html.insert(wrapper);
    }
  });
});
```

Author i can edit and content. But when content is empty - delete this block.
Can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you will need to add to "toolbarButtons", the name of your command created like:

```
$("#element").froalaEditor({
    toolbarButtons: ["customQuote"]
});
```